# What do the abbreviations "мн." and "ч." mean?

Tags: словарь, сокращения

On the [wiktionary page for дар (gift)](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80), in some of the definitions, the abbreviations "мн." and "ч." appear, what do they mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"мн.ч." is just the abbreviation for "множественное число" (the plural form).

You'll also see "ед.ч" there, which stands for "единственное число" (the singular form).

Comment: The full list of abbreviations can be found on the main page of ru.wiktionary.org via the link [Условные сокращения](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). "Мн.ч." is in the section "Грамматические категории".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: “singular/plural number”, as per Anixx’s edit, are valid terminology, as it relates to a [grammatical category of number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number).